# Switching LaTeX files from latin-1 to utf-8: "Keyboard character used is undefined"

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings

My .tex and .sty files were in encoding latin-1.  I've converted
them [using Emacs] to utf-8.

In my sty file, I replaced

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

:: The problem: My style file has commands

```
\newcommand{°}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{½}{\ensuremath{\frac{1}{2}}}
```

and the like.

When I run command `pdflatex' from the command line, I
get this error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.86 \newcommand{Â°}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
```

which is showing the character as

```
Â°
```

Is there a way to get these characters processed in
utf-8, or should I switch back to latin-1?

============
[I'm not sure the stackexchange method to Ulrike Fischer's
suggestion, so I'm editing my original question.

Alas, neither solution is working on my system [which is
 "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live
 2010)"], or I may be mis-applying your suggestion.

Running `pdfTeX' on

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

\begin{document}

Test: $ ½ $

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./de.testing.latex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian
, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, u
kenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, 
german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, assamese,
 bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, 
telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, roma
nian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish,
 turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/Users/squash/Texdir/Pkgs/newunicodechar.sty) (./de.testing.aux)

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:½ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 $½
        $
?
```

This happens whether or not the "\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}"
is present, and whether or not the
"\usepackage{newunicodechar}" is present.

Comment: Use either the newunicodechar package or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}` (after inputenc).

Comment: Neither solution working on my system.  I've edited my question putting in a minimal-example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer's suggestion is to do `\newunicodechar{°}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}` and `\newunicodechar{½}{\ensuremath{\frac{1}{2}}}` and it does work. When you load a package you should give a quick look at its documentation: `texdoc newunicodechar`.

Comment: Thanks jfbu.  Running `texdoc newunicodechar' was the first thing I did.  On my system, it gave: "Sorry, no documentation found for newunicodechar."  (I did eventually get the doc by hand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ulrike's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392346/switching-latex-files-from-latin-1-to-utf-8-keyboard-character-used-is-undefin#comment974800_392346) works like a charm, e.g. package `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{½}{\ensuremath{\frac{1}{2}}}

\begin{document}

Test: $ ½ $

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The hexadecimal Unicode number needs to be known without package `newunicodechar`:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BD}{\ensuremath{\frac{1}{2}}
```

The font encoding `TS1`, loaded by package `textcomp` contains a slot for this symbol and uses the *text* mode character `\textonehalf`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

Test: ½

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ah ha!  I need to use  \newunicodechar  rather than \newcommand.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Heiko and Ulrike. I indeed had already tried

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
```

without using \DeclareUnicodeCharacter, but I had kept the
commands as they were, e.g

```
\newcommand{·}{\cdot}
```

This caused an error that was obscure to me.  Replacing the
latter with

```
\newunicodechar{·}{\cdot}
```

made more of my style-files load.

It turned out that while my former latin-1 setup accepted
expressions such as

```
$ \boldsymbol· $
```

they now cause an error.  My current UTF8 setup only works
if I put in braces,

```
$ \boldsymbol{·} $
```

That is, it seems that when characters

```
¼  ±  ·
```

and the like, are passed as arguments to a macro, they must
be in braces.  Or perhaps I have mis-set-up something.

In any case, my files are compiling now after a bunch of
global search-replacements.  Thanks again.